# How can I detect swipes on Spritekit Nodes?

Tags: ios, swift3, sprite-kit, uigesturerecognizer, swipe

So I am currently working on a 2D endless runner written in Swift3 and using Spritekit for my nodes and scenes. I recently implemented some code to detect swipes in general, they will be below. So my question is: how can I detect a swipe action and check the direction of that swipe on a Spritekit Node? I realize that this has been asked before, but I cannot find a working solution since everything I come across seems to be for Swift and Swift2, not Swift3.

Here's my swipe detection code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
  super.viewDidLoad()
  let swipeLeft = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.respondToSwipeGesture))
    swipeLeft.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.left
    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(swipeLeft)

    let swipeRight = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.respondToSwipeGesture))
    swipeRight.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.right
    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(swipeRight)

    let swipeUp = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.respondToSwipeGesture))
    swipeUp.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.up
    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(swipeUp)

    let swipeDown = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.respondToSwipeGesture))
    swipeDown.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.down
    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(swipeDown)
}
```

I have tested these with a function:

```
func respondToSwipeGesture(gesture: UIGestureRecognizer) {
        if let swipeGesture = gesture as? UISwipeGestureRecognizer {
            switch swipeGesture.direction {
            case UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.right:
                print("Swiped right")
            case UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.down:
                print("Swiped down")
            case UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.left:
                print("Swiped left")
            case UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.up:
                print("Swiped up")
            default:
                break
            }
        }
}
```

The swipes seem to work all right, as the print statements have been displaying the correct outputs in response to my swipes.

I have also added a delegate to avoid possible SIGABRT errors:

```
class GameViewController: UIViewController, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate
```

Please let me know if you'd like more information!

> Edit:
>   Added code where I initialized my puzzle pieces

```
//The class
class ChoosePiecesClass: SKSpriteNode{
    func moveWithCamera() {
        self.position.x += 5;
}


//initialize a piece
private var RandomPiece1: ChoosePiecesClass?;


override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
    RandomPiece1 = childNode(withName: "RandomPiece1") as? ChoosePiecesClass;
    RandomPiece1?.position.x = 195;
    RandomPiece1?.position.y = -251;
}

override func update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval) {
    RandomPiece1?.moveWithCamera();
}
```

> Edited to provide the error statement from console, upon clicking Start Game and triggering the fatalError code, causing the game to crash.

```
fatal error: init(coder:) has not been implemented: file /Users/ardemis/Documents/PuzzleRunner/PuzzleRunner 3 V3/PuzzleRunner/ChoosePieces.swift, line 33
```

It also displays the following

```
EXEC_BAT_INSTRUCTION(code = EXEC_1386_INVOP, subcode = 0x0)
```

on the same line as the fatalError declaration.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I wouldn't use the UIGestures if I was trying to track specific SpriteNodes. You can easily track your nodes in TouchesBegan and figure out which way a swipe direction occurs. This example has three sprites on the screen on will print/log whatever direction one of them gets swiped and will ignore all other swipes.

> EDIT > I just created a subclass for my Box object (sorry I didn't use your naming, but it has the same functions). There are probably many ways of doing this, I chose to use create a protocol on the subclass and make the scene conform to the protocol. I moved all of the touch/swipe functionality into the sub class, and when it is done detecting the swipe it just calls the delegate and says which object has been swiped.

```
protocol BoxDelegate: NSObjectProtocol {
    func boxSwiped(box: Box)
}

class Box: SKSpriteNode {

    weak var boxDelegate: BoxDelegate!
    private var moveAmtX: CGFloat = 0
    private var moveAmtY: CGFloat = 0
    private let minimum_detect_distance: CGFloat = 100
    private var initialPosition: CGPoint = CGPoint.zero
    private var initialTouch: CGPoint = CGPoint.zero
    private var resettingSlider = false

    override init(texture: SKTexture?, color: UIColor, size: CGSize) {

        super.init(texture: texture, color: color, size: size)

        self.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    func moveWithCamera() {
        self.position.x += 5
    }

    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

        if let touch = touches.first as UITouch! {

            initialTouch = touch.location(in: self.scene!.view)
            moveAmtY = 0
            moveAmtX = 0
            initialPosition = self.position
        }
    }

    override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

        if let touch = touches.first as UITouch! {

            let movingPoint: CGPoint = touch.location(in: self.scene!.view)

            moveAmtX = movingPoint.x - initialTouch.x
            moveAmtY = movingPoint.y - initialTouch.y
        }
    }

    override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

        var direction = ""
        if fabs(moveAmtX) > minimum_detect_distance {

            //must be moving side to side
            if moveAmtX < 0 {
                direction = "left"
            }
            else {
                direction = "right"
            }
        }
        else if fabs(moveAmtY) > minimum_detect_distance {

            //must be moving up and down
            if moveAmtY < 0 {
                direction = "up"
            }
            else {
                direction = "down"
            }
        }

        print("object \(self.name!) swiped " + direction)

        self.boxDelegate.boxSwiped(box: self)
    }
}
```

In GameScene.sks

> Make sure to make GameScene conform to BoxDelegate by adding the protocol after the declaration

```
class GameScene: SKScene, BoxDelegate {

    var box = Box()
    var box2 = Box()
    var box3 = Box()

    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {

        box = Box(color: .white, size: CGSize(width: 200, height: 200))
        box.zPosition = 1
        box.position = CGPoint(x: 0 - 900, y: 0)
        box.name = "white box"
        box.boxDelegate = self
        addChild(box)

        box2 = Box(color: .blue, size: CGSize(width: 200, height: 200))
        box2.zPosition = 1
        box2.name = "blue box"
        box2.position = CGPoint(x: 0 - 600, y: 0)
        box2.boxDelegate = self
        addChild(box2)

        box3 = Box(color: .red, size: CGSize(width: 200, height: 200))
        box3.zPosition = 1
        box3.name = "red box"
        box3.position = CGPoint(x: -300, y: 0)
        box3.boxDelegate = self
        addChild(box3)
    }

    func boxSwiped(box: Box) {
        currentObject = box
        print("currentObject \(currentObject)")
    }

    override func update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval) {
        box.moveWithCamera()
        box2.moveWithCamera()
        box3.moveWithCamera()
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi there, this works amazingly, thank you so much! The code is also very pretty. I will upvote it as soon as I get 15 points under my belt. I do have a little problem, however: I'm working with puzzle pieces that are procedurally generated and they populate slots. I had declared them as a class with func moveWithCamera() that constantly increments their x-values by 5, matching the speed of the camera. I know how to replace the boxes with the textures that I need, with box.texture, but I have no idea how to keep them moving with the camera. I should have put this in my original post, dang!

Comment: Ran out of characters!
Just to clarify further, because I am horrible at explaining things: the slots are persistent, they move with the camera therefore so did the previous selectable (via swipe) puzzle pieces within. I plan to replace those pieces with these boxes, re-textured as pieces.

Comment: are the puzzle pieces their own subclass of SKSpriteNode?

Comment: @Ardemis I'll take a look at it just add the code where you initialize your puzzle piece to your question

Comment: Yessir, the code has been updated. I believe that I have declared it correctly as a subclass of SKSpriteNode. I realize that my line where I declare RandomPiece1 as a node already in my scene seems counter-intuitive to my procedural generation goal. I was hoping that I could use the method you suggested and achieve the goal better that way, because mine is quite hard-coded and it seems that I would be able to pass the "boxes" textures on the fly, via changing a string right?

Comment: @Ardemis I've updated my answer. It works great it evens the boxes scrolling across the scene waiting to be swiped

Comment: Thank you for the insanely quick reply! I am unfortunately unable to implement your solution at this time, but I will reply with the results ASAP. Thanks again!

Comment: No Probs, I'm bachelorin' tonight so I had nothing better to do! Good Luck

Comment: Well, I finally left that dreadful emergency meeting. But anyway, I've put in your code and everything except the required init? seems to be in favor of compiling. Would you happen to know why that is? If it makes a difference, I have a menu screen as well, from which you start the game. The fatal error only occurs once I have clicked start game from that menu...I'm guessing from loading the nodes? Choosing the store option does not return the same error and works as intended.

Comment: @Ardemis are you adding your pieces via the scene editor?

Comment: I initially was but I have changed it so that it adds with your approach now, since it seems more logical as I prepare to implement procedural generation of these pieces. I do have a a permanent starting platform of about 8 physics pieces though, but if I'm correct, that should not affect it right?

Comment: 8 physics pieces shouldn't cause any performance issues unless they are incredibly complex objects. even then 8 shouldn't be an issue

Comment: Ah, thanks. It seems that I misnamed something while I was incorporating it into my code. I also got a fatal error from `self.boxDelegate.boxSwiped(box: self)` when I swiped a box, after adding your code and making sure everything looked right. By removing it, it still tells me which box is swiped as normal, and nothing seems to be out of place. Is it safe for me to leave it out, rather than troubleshoot it?

Comment: It is just probably printing out to the screen that you swiped. You'll need to figure out where the disconnect is if you want the GameScene to do something special with your swiped piece. if I had to guess I would check whether or not you added the Delegate after GameScene and whether or not you are assigning the box,delegate = self when creating the objects

Comment: I will check that as soon as possible. I believe that I have already bothered you for far too long, so I just have one last question. I don't actually plan to do much with the pieces that I am swiping, as long as the game detects it--as it does now. I just want to hide the piece, then spawn a platform piece as a result. I imagine that I can simply add `if self.name == "BottomOpen" {
            //spawn BottomOpen piece as next platform piece, up or right or down dependent on direction value
            //hide self
        }` onto the end of touchesEnded right?

Comment: Here's the thing...The TouchesEnded is in a subclass for the object, which is good because the code is encapsulated with that object. The code you want to run really should be run/controlled from a main Game Scene, and not the objects. technically one piece doesn't know about another piece, but GameScene know anout all of them. That's why I was using the protocol to send the info back to GameScene. So based on the limited knowledge I have of what your doing I would probably have a different class for your platform pieces.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142678/discussion-between-ron-myschuk-and-ardemis).